# How to join denormalized data that goes two+ levels deep in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, nosql

Here's the scenario: I have a list of topics, each topic includes posts, and each post was "liked" by a list of users. Thus my data looks something like this:

```
"topics": {
    "topic1": {
        "posts": {
            "post1": true,
            "post2": true
        }
     }
 },
 "posts": {
     "post1": {
         "title": "An awesome post",
         "likes": {
             "user1": true
         }
     },
     "post2": {
         "title": "An even better post",
         "likes": {
             "user1": true,
             "user2": true
         }
     }
 },
 "users": {
     "user1": {
         "name": "Mr. T",
         "email": "t@t.com"
     },
     "user2": {
         "name": "Mr. Hello World",
         "email": "hello@world.com"
     }
 }
```

I (think I) know how to get all posts for the topic using Firebase.util (http://firebase.github.io/firebase-util):

```
Firebase.util.intersection(
    fb.child('topics').child('topic1').child('posts'),
    fb.child('posts')
)
```

But now I would like each post to include the names of the users who liked the post. How does one do that?

Probably won't change anything, but this is all happening in AngularFire.

Comment: hou didn't ask what you want to query. Is it all posts liked by one user? or all users who liked posts in one topic?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. In this case, I'd like to see all the names of the users who liked a post. So if you're looking at posts/post2, I'd like to see "Liked by Mr. T and Mr. Hello World!"

Comment: so instead of using "true" as value in likes you could use his name

Comment: Fair enough. I think coming from a SQL background, I was hesitant about truly denormalizing my data (and instead followed the advice here https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html) but perhaps I should just bite the bullet and denormalize everywhere. Thanks for taking a look at this and sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See a working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/LCa6j/)

The gist of this sort of denormalization is to fetch the users as you grab posts. It's nothing more complex than it sounds. Just go grab them.

Firebase does a lot of work internally to optimize requests and re-uses the same socket connection for all the listeners, so this is quite performant--barely more overhead than the amount of bytes being downloaded, regardless of whether they are split into separate paths or stored together.

The HTML:

```
<h3>Normalizing user profiles into posts</h3>

<ul ng-controller="ctrl">
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts | orderByPriority" ng-init="user = users.$load(post.user)">
        {{user.name}}: {{post.title}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

The JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase']);
var fb = new Firebase(URL);

app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $firebase, userCache) {
    $scope.posts = $firebase(fb.child('posts'));
    $scope.users = userCache(fb.child('users'));
});

app.factory('userCache', function ($firebase) {
    return function (ref) {
        var cachedUsers = {};
        cachedUsers.$load = function (id) {
            if( !cachedUsers.hasOwnProperty(id) ) {
                cachedUsers[id] = $firebase(ref.child(id));
            }
            return cachedUsers[id];
        };
        cachedUsers.$dispose = function () {
            angular.forEach(cachedUsers, function (user) {
                user.$off();
            });
        };
        return cachedUsers;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kato. This is awesome. Despite all the things that Firebase does to make things super efficient, would it still be more performance if the data was more fully denormalized (i.e. all the user info was replicated) or is performance basically the same?

Comment: Certainly less requests will be faster, at least initially. But as with most things, one shouldn't bother optimizing unless there is an actual problem. As you can see in the fiddle, it's too fast to even notice that it makes three round trips. At a couple hundred records, it could be noticeable, but probably still quite performant.